# How to split one date column into two columns and get data from the start date to last date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to split a column in two and display the data between first date and last date no data repetition?

I am working on a SQL Server database I want to display three column from the table I have. I tried in many ways but it not do what is needed. Original table is like this below:

```
Refno       TransactionDate          Code
-----------------------------------------
L820774729  2012-09-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2012-09-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2012-10-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2012-10-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2012-12-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-01-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-02-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-03-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-03-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-04-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-06-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-09-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-10-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-10-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  99
L820774729  2013-12-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-01-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-02-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-03-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-04-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-05-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-06-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-07-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-08-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-08-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-08-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000  2 
L820774729  2014-10-01 00:00:00.000  2
L820774729  2014-11-01 00:00:00.000  1
L820774729  2014-12-01 00:00:00.000  1
L820774729  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  1
L820774729  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000  1
L820774729  2015-03-01 00:00:00.000  1
L820774729  2015-04-01 00:00:00.000  1
L820774729  2015-05-01 00:00:00.000  1
L820774729  2015-06-01 00:00:00.000  1
```

The output that is needed is like this.

```
From      To        Code
------------------------
Sep 2012  Oct 2013  99
Nov 2013  Nov 2013  2
Nov 2013  Nov 2013  99
Dec 2013  Oct 2014  2
Nov 2014  Jun 2015  1
```

but my current code is like this

```
SELECT 
    [Refno]As Ref,
    [TransactionDate] As [From],
    (SELECT MIN(TransactionDate) 
     FROM LevyTransactions AS LlevyTransactions
     WHERE LlevyTransactions.TransactionDate > LevyTransactions.TransactionDate) AS [To],
    [Code]
FROM 
    dbo.LevyTransactions 
WHERE 
    Refno = 'L82077479'
```

and my current output is like this.

```
From                     To                       Code
------------------------------------------------------
2012-09-01 00:00:00.000  2012-10-01 00:00:00.000  99
2012-09-01 00:00:00.000  2012-10-01 00:00:00.000  99 
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000  2012-11-01 00:00:00.000  99
2012-10-01 00:00:00.000  2012-11-01 00:00:00.000  99
2012-12-01 00:00:00.000  2013-01-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-01-01 00:00:00.000  2013-02-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-02-01 00:00:00.000  2013-03-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-03-01 00:00:00.000  2013-04-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-03-01 00:00:00.000  2013-04-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-04-01 00:00:00.000  2013-05-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-06-01 00:00:00.000  2013-07-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-07-01 00:00:00.000  2013-08-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-09-01 00:00:00.000  2013-10-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-10-01 00:00:00.000  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-10-01 00:00:00.000  2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  2013-12-01 00:00:00.000  2
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  2013-12-01 00:00:00.000  2
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  2013-12-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-11-01 00:00:00.000  2013-12-01 00:00:00.000  99
2013-12-01 00:00:00.000  2014-01-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000  2014-02-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-02-01 00:00:00.000  2014-03-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-03-01 00:00:00.000  2014-04-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-04-01 00:00:00.000  2014-05-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000  2014-06-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-06-01 00:00:00.000  2014-07-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-07-01 00:00:00.000  2014-08-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000  2014-09-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-09-01 00:00:00.000  2014-10-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-10-01 00:00:00.000  2014-11-01 00:00:00.000  2
2014-11-01 00:00:00.000  2014-12-01 00:00:00.000  1
2014-12-01 00:00:00.000  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  1
2014-12-01 00:00:00.000  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  1
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  2015-02-01 00:00:00.000  1
2015-02-01 00:00:00.000  2015-03-01 00:00:00.000  1
2015-03-01 00:00:00.000  2015-04-01 00:00:00.000  1
2015-04-01 00:00:00.000  2015-05-01 00:00:00.000  1
2015-05-01 00:00:00.000  2015-06-01 00:00:00.000  1
2015-06-01 00:00:00.000  NULL                     1
```

Please help me if you have any idea about the solution.

Even if you have idea of doing it on c#.net no problem you can reply please help me.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the `[...]` usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just Gordon's answer with a fix on column name. It should output the result you want.

```
WITH cte AS(
    select *, (row_number() over (partition by ref order by [TransactionDate]) -
            row_number() over (partition by ref, code order by [TransactionDate])
           ) as group_no
    from LevyTransactions t
)
SELECT
  Ref, MIN(Code) AS Code, MIN(TransactionDate) AS StartDate, MAX(TransactionDate) AS EndDate
FROM cte
GROUP BY Ref, group_no
ORDER BY 1,3
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/069b0/15)

---

**Edit:** To get the display format as you mentioned, please use the following query

```
WITH cte AS(
    select *, (row_number() over (partition by ref order by [TransactionDate]) -
            row_number() over (partition by ref, code order by [TransactionDate])
           ) as group_no
    from LevyTransactions t
)
SELECT
  Ref
  ,MIN(Code) AS Code
  ,STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MIN(TransactionDate),107), 4,4, ' ') AS [From]
  ,STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MAX(TransactionDate),107), 4,4, ' ') AS [To]
FROM cte
GROUP BY Ref, group_no
ORDER BY Ref,MIN(TransactionDate)
```

Comment: Wow thank you EricZ it working. @EricZ. Thank to you too Gordon. You save my life guys.

Comment: Only thing which is working is to display the month and year only in TransactionDate column. I want to apply  this select LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, SYSDATETIME()), 3) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, SYSDATETIME())AS [Mon YYYY] so that it can display the month and year only is it possible to do it how can I add this any Idea please.

Comment: @MuziwenhlanhlaDlamini, answer updated with the display format

Comment: do you have any knowledge how to create a stored procedures? I want to create stored procedures for this table with two parameters FROM & TO. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want.  One method is a difference of row numbers.  It turns out that the following expression is constant when values are the same:

```
select (row_number() over (partition by ref order by [TransactionDate]) -
        row_number() over (partition by ref, code order by [TransactionDate])
       ) as grp
from LevyTransactions t;
```

You can try it and see for yourself.

The rest is just aggregation:

```
select ref, code, min(TransactionDate), max(TransactionDate)
from (select (row_number() over (partition by ref order by TransactionDate) -
              row_number() over (partition by ref, code order by [TransactionDate])
             ) as grp
      from LevyTransactions t
     ) t
group by ref, code, grp;
```

Comment: No it not working Gordon it just give me this out put:

Comment: (No column name)
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
15
15
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
2

Comment: do you have any knowledge how to create a stored procedures? I want to create stored procedures for this table with two parameters FROM & TO. Please help.